# I would like to make a round shape with an extrude?

Tags: edit-mode, bevel, extrude

I would like to make this round shape, like on the table legs in the picture ? it's possible ? Ty !
[image]

Comment: You could use the Scale tool with proportional editing turned on, but with a complex shape like that it would probably be better to use a Bezier curve with the Screw modifier. [Here's](https://youtu.be/Grb-k5irp00) a quick tutorial.

Comment: Yes good idea ty ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a 16 vertex cylinder, create some horizontal edge loops:

[image]

Select 3 vertices out of 4 all around:

[image]

Scale:

[image]

Continue to scale, bevel, etc:

[image]

Comment: ok i will try, thanks!!